# Override read function, but i have problems when the file descripot is 3 or 4

Tags: c, netstat, ld-preload

I want to override the read function of netstat -tunap, when am running the strace for netstat -tunap the part that i am interested on overriding is this part right here,

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 4096) = 300
write(1, "tcp        0      0 192.168.32.1"..., 101tcp        0      0 192.168.32.128:59904    192.168.32.129:9001     ESTABLISHED 17186/python ) = 101
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)
```

What i want is to see the contents of the buffer of this line here

```
read(3, "  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 4096) = 300
```

But the read librbary that am LD_PREALOADING is only prints me the buffers of reads with file descriptors of 5, This is how the read looks with file descriptor 5

```
read(5, "unconfined\n", 4095)           = 11
```

how can i fix it to get it to print the buffers with file descriptor of 3 as well?

This is the program I used for the library,

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static ssize_t (*read_original)(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) = NULL;

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    ssize_t result;

    // Initialize the original read function if it hasn't been already
    if (!read_original) {
        read_original = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
        if (!read_original) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to load the original read function\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // Call the original read function
    result = read_original(fd, buf, count);

    // Print the buffer's contents for non-zero reads
    if (result > 0 && (fd == 3 || fd == 4 || fd == 5)) {
        printf("Read from fd %d, %zd bytes: ", fd, result);
        for (ssize_t i = 0; i < result; ++i) {
            printf("%02x ", ((unsigned char *)buf)[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return result;
}
```

I create the library like this

`gcc -shared -fPIC -o hider.so hide_read4.c -ldl`

and i run it like this

`LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/lib/hider.so  netstat -tunap`

And this is the output when I run this command

```
Read from fd 5, 11 bytes: 75 6e 63 6f 6e 66 69 6e 65 64 0a 
Read from fd 5, 11 bytes: 75 6e 63 6f 6e 66 69 6e 65 64 0a 
Read from fd 5, 11 bytes: 75 6e 63 6f 6e 66 69 6e 65 64 0a 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 ip1:59904    ip2:9001     ESTABLISHED 17186/python        
udp        0      0 ip1:68       ip3:67       ESTABLISHED -
```

Comment: Cool snooper. It works just like you describe for me too unfortunately - but it seems to work fine on many other programs.  Unrelated to the problem: You could create a `void __attribute__ ((constructor)) ctor(void) { ... }` function to call `dlsym` so that you don't have to check if it's assigned in every call to `read`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Or protect `read_original` with a mutex - the current implementation is a race condition in a multithreaded process: if it's `NULL`, lock the mutex and check again.  I'd be worried that `read()` might get called *before* such a constructor were called as other libraries could also have constructors.

Comment: Also, the `read()` in the `strace` output for fd 3 could be from a direct system call from something like `fopen()`, or a `libc`-internal call directly to another `read()` implementation from some other library call.  Or maybe even just a call to `_read()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, the current one has a race. Fixing it with a mutex would work but then you'd have that overhead in each call. I don't think a call to the `read` in `hider.so` is possible without the constructor having been executed. I don't see how that'd be possible and I've never had issues with it (even though that doesn't prove anything). I see you figured out OPs problem below. Nice, +1.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code gremlins must have read my comment.  I literally just spent four hours fixing a deadlock in `__attribute__((constructor))` functions that only appeared if the library was loaded dynamically with `dlopen()`.  It worked fine as a link-time dependency.  It was because of the order the constructors were called between several interdependent libraries.  Even with `LD_PRELOAD` set, I don't think there's any guarantee that `hider.so`'s constructor will run *first* in all cases.  Note that later GCC versions allow you to specify a constructor "priority", but only one can be first

Comment: @AndrewHenle :-O Wow! Ok, will be careful with this in the future. I wonder if a C++ lazy initialization solution would be able to solve it? Or just a `static` in the `read` function. It's usually easier to initialize "complex" things in C++ safely I think.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Annoying. I tried `extern "C" {
ssize_t read(int fd, void* buf, size_t count) { static const auto original = loader<decltype(&read)>("read"); ...` where `loader` is a function template that does `template<class F>
static F loader(const char* const symbol) { return reinterpret_cast<F>(::dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, symbol)); }` but for some reason, this `read` doesn't intercept the calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netstat` uses `fgets()` in this case to read lines from `/proc/net/tcp`.  Using `ltrace netstat -tunap` tool, these calls in the `strace` output:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 4096) = 300
write(1, "tcp        0      0 192.168.32.1"..., 101tcp        0      0 192.168.32.128:59904    192.168.32.129:9001     ESTABLISHED 17186/python ) = 101
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)
```

map to the following library calls:

```
fopen64("/proc/net/tcp", "r")                                                               = 0x564c3a8172a0
setvbuf(0x564c3a8172a0, 0x564c3a81a8a0, 0, 4096)                                            = 0
fgets("  sl  local_address rem_address "..., 8192, 0x564c3a8172a0)                          = 0x7fff68214ac0
feof(0x564c3a8172a0)                                                                        = 0
  .
  .
  .
fgets("  28: 9801A8C0:A6D4 6310FB8E:01B"..., 8192, 0x564c3a8172a0)                          = 0
feof(0x564c3a8172a0)                                                                        = 1
fclose(0x564c3a8172a0)                                                                      = 0
```

Comment: Yes i was using strace, thanks to you i used ltrace, and i figured it out. My goal was to hide a connection that was found in /proc/net/tcp, i hide it by overriding the fopen64 function when it finds the /proc/net/tcp, to redirect it to an arbitrary file containing all the connections of the /proc/net/tcp exect the one i want to hide. Thank you very much